# How to install a specific python3 version on Alpine?

Tags: python, linux, docker, alpine-linux

If I run:

```
RUN apk add --update --no-cache python3 && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN python3 -m ensurepip
RUN pip3 install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools
```

This install Python version 3.9 on my Alpine, but because I Work with Django 1.10.5 it gives me errors, so I need to install python 3.5.
How can I specify this?

Comment: did you try to use `python3.5` and `pip3.5` ?

Answer (score 2):

Doing [package pinning](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Package_management#Holding_a_specific_package_back) in Alpine might break at any point if you are not maintaining your own version of the package repository because of their policy regarding their packages:

> We don't at the moment have resources to store all built packages indefinitely in our infra. Thus we currently keep only the latest for each stable branch, and has always been like that.
>
> PyPi and npm just keep source versions. We have to do binary builds which are considerably larger, and may need to be redone when one of the dependencies changes. So as whole this is a magnitude more difficult and storage hungry problem. Of course it is unfortunate that the same rules applies to all packages, even to the python/npm ones that would not need to be rebuilt as often as they are source distributions.
>
> There has been discussion of keep all packages tagged as Alpine in the future. However, this is still "in-progress". The official recommendation is to keep your own mirror / repository with all the specific package and their versions that you may want to use.

*<sup>Source: https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/abuild/-/issues/9996#note_87135</sup>*

A better idea, in order to achieve this, would be to come from a [`python`](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) image, right away.

So your Dockerfile would start with:

```sh
FROM python:3.5-alpine

## Here goes your `RUN` commands, without the need to install python and pip,
## since they are build in the base image already
```